# Pass expression in known assembly via serialization

Tags: c#, .net, linq, serialization

**Short Description**

Looking for a good way to pass a serialized representation of an arbitrary `System.Linq.Expression` via network. Both client/server have access to the same assemblies.

**Details**

I have a client/server setup in which a client is able to invoke a set of predefined remote methods on a server by using Orleans (You don't need to know any details on that, just FYI). When calling a method from the client, parameters to this method are serialized, see this example:

```
// Method defined on the server
Task FilterBy(Func<MyObject, bool> func) { ... }

// Client calling that method
remote.FilterBy(o => o.Value > 42 && o.MethodCall() == "Foo")
```

This works for passing delegate types such as `Func` since the server also references the assembly containing the autogenerated class from the lambda above. However, the server needs to know details on the underlying `Expression` since it does some processing on the expression tree. 
I took a look at some libraries such as [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) for serializing an `Expression`. Unfortunately this library does not work with the expression above, since it contains this `o.MethodCall()`. Also, using a library like this would be overkill, since both the client and server know the assembly defining this query.

Is there a nice way to pass the lambda expression as an actual `Expression` considering the fact that both the client and the server have access to the assembly containing the lambda expression?

**Possible Solutions**

I came up with the following solutions which I don't think are ideal. Thus, I'm looking forward to your approaches :).

1. Send a unique identification of a LINQ expression, e.g. by assigning a GUID to it and provide lookup in a static class. I really don't like the fact all expressions would be defined in one class and not where they logically belong.
2. A more feasible approach, which I do not like due to its verbosity would be to change the method signature, so the client passes the delegate which returns an `Expression`:

   ```
   // Method signature
   void FilterBy(Func<Expression<Func<MyObject, bool>>> func) { ... }

   // Client calling that method
   remote.FilterBy(() => (o => o.Value > 42 && o.MethodCall() == "Foo"))
   ```

Comment: You are really trying to send binary data between two applications.  The data has to be in a structure which can be decoded.  It is probably easier to serialize and send the xml serialization, or binary serialization.  Both would require constructing a structure or class defining the data organization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A short disclaimer first: having server and client communicate in terms of binary serialized data from one assembly is the best service contract, as it is not interoperable and tightly coupled. 
It would be best to express your service contract in terms of list of methods with pre-defined parameters, are you absolutely sure you have to support all possible filters?*

Expression class, which is the base class for all expressions is **not marked with SerializableAttribute**, so it cannot be serialized.
As a workaround, people often mirror the Expression class hierarchy, taking just a subset that they need, and marking their classes as serializable. Then, you would need to implement a visitor to re-write System.Linq.Epression to your expression types. This is rather time consuming and boring task, since class hierarchy of System.Linq.Epressions is very broad.

I would suggest you take your approach #1 with slight modifications:

1. Avoid GUIDs and use descriptive names
2. Logically group expressions into different classes
3. Declare expressions as class fields
4. Register all of the expressions in one Registry (registry pattern)
5. Consider using reflection (or registration via IOC container) for step above to avoid manual mistakes
6. Pass the argument and expression name in service calls

If you don't accept the approach above you could resort to a subset of grammar supported by Serialize.Linq. Perhaps some of the methods do not do heavy computations and can be re-formulated as properties.

Comment: I just discovered a ford of [metalinq](https://github.com/mcintyre321/metalinq) that opposed to Serialize.Linq is able to deal with method invocations. It seems like this is enough for now. If not, I will reconsider the approach you mention. I totally agree with your disclaimer's concerns. However, the `FilterBy` function has to be compatible with arbitrary filters.

Comment: @BenjiWa, great that you have a solution! I was not aware of MetaLinq.
Read about it and it looks like it is taking the approach I described - mirroring Expression class hierarchy with EditableExpression derived classes. Nice that someone already did that mundane piece of work!